# batch script for svn auto commit

Tags: batch-file, svn

I need batch script which will find out only the files with `.config` extension in a directory, after it should do svn status operation on those files.

1. If svn status is `?` then it should perform `svn add` command on that file.
2. If svn status is `!` then it should perform `svn delete` command on that file.

After that it should commit all those files to repository.

I have the below code it's working for all file perfectly, but i need it only for files which have `.config` extension

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn status %1 ^| find "?"') do svn add "%%i"
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn status %1 ^| find "!"') do svn delete "%%i"
svn commit -m "Automatic commit" %1
```

Comment: How about using svn status and using it output selecting only files that would have .config extension?

Comment: it sounds like your real problem is how you are getting in this situation